# How should i structure my MongoDb database? A lot of small documents or embedded fewer documents?

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am new to python and very new to MongoDb. I made an application to store trivia questions, currently in a json. This is how the overall structure looks like:

[image]

This is an example of single answer questions, in art category:[image]

And this is an example of multiple choice questions in art category :

[image]

As you can see, in both cases i use the question itself as key and it's answer as value. So, to get the answer to a question i would just do: `answers = dictionary["multiple"]["art"]["What is a sitar?"]` and i would get :

```
["Instrument",
"Food",
"Insect",
"Temple"]
```

My application runs as you would expect. When i get a new question, i know it's subject (art, biology, etc). If question doesn't exist i just add it in the right category.

I want to move all my saved questions and answers in a MongoDb database. But if i add the whole json as a single document in a collection, whenever i do a query to look for a question : answer pair, the whole document is returned, since is the only one.
If i try to make 2 documents("single", "multiple"), it will still return the whole "single" document. If i go even lower and do just "art", "biology", etc. documents i will have duplicates since i have "art" for both singleAnswer and multipleChoice. Should i just name the documents "single.art", "multiple.art". If so, what would a query for the below condition look like?

```
`if not "What is a sitar?" in dictionary["multiple"]["art"]:
   dictionary["multiple"]["art"]["What is a sitar?"] : 
                            ["Instrument","Food","Insect","Temple"]
```

`

I have done all of this scenarios mentioned above except the last one, and i found that every time i query, it returns the whole object when all i need is a single question and it's answer(if it exists). Am i missing something or maybe i expect this to still work as a json(dictionary)? Thank you!

**Edit:**

Found this in MongoDb documentation. Would my scenario qualify as a hierarchical relationship? Meaning that every question belongs in a certain subject and every subject in it's own category (single, multiple)

> Documents can be nested to express hierarchical relationships and to store structures such as arrays.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your design is very smart. Dynamic field names are usually difficult to handle, the queries are complex and it is very hard to index them.

I would propose data model like this:

```
{ 
   type: "multiple",
   categroy: "art",
   questions: [
      {
         question: "What is a sitar?",
         choice: ["Instrument","Food","Insect","Temple","Village"],
         answers: ["Instrument","Village"]
      },
      {
         question: ...,
         choice: ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Or even one document for each question.

Comment: The reason i added categories like (simple,multiple) and subjects (art,biology,math) is because when i receive a new question, i know exactly the category and subject. So to check if it exists in database, i dont have to look through all the questions, instead i look in the exact place. If i have 100 questions per subject, (1000 pe category) , instead of looking through 2000 questions, i will only have too look through 100. The point was to find a needle in the smallest haystack possible. Am i wrong in thinking this is how the database works?

Comment: In general your approach might work. Image you have a few thousands of questions, it's impossible to create an index which speeds up your query. Instead of loading only the question you like to get, you always need to read the entire database into your memory. It works for a small school project but it does not scale at all.

Comment: Ok. Just as an idea, i have stored around 19k questions so far. And i think i will probably have around 40k in total. Sorry if i'm pusing it already, but do you think having multiple collections would work if i name the collection category.subject? Eg: single.art, single.biology....multiple.art, multiple.biology. So that when i query i can look exactly in the collection that contains the category and subject. Then every document in the collection will be a single question : answer pair.

Comment: **Update**: Found this in the MongoDb documentation: `Perhaps the most powerful feature of document databases is the ability to nest objects inside of documents. A good rule of thumb for structuring data in MongoDB is to prefer embedding data inside documents to breaking it apart into separate collections, unless you have a good reason (like needing to store unbounded lists of items, or needing to look up objects directly without retrieving a parent document).`

Comment: Similar documents should be stored in one collection, there is not reason to spread them over several collections. Yes, nested documents is a powerful feature and a major difference to traditional relational RDBMS. My main criticism is that you use dynamic (and somehow unpredictable) field names.